# Adding up a list of subscripted elements

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of entries with subscripts. I want to add just the entries. How can I do that in the presence of subscripts?
For example:

```
list = {1a, 2b, 3c}
```

And I want to do the sum where the answer should come out to be 6 (please note that a, b and c represent the subscripts).

Comment: `{Subscript[1, a], Subscript[2, b], Subscript[3, c]} /. 
  Subscript[x_, _] :> x // Tr`

Comment: @belisarius - or `Tr[First /@ {Subscript[1, a], Subscript[2, b], Subscript[3, c]}]`

Comment: `Tr@list[[All, 1]]`

Comment: `List @@@ % // Total // First` :)

Comment: Well, after so many comments this leaves me with the shortest version: `%`

Answer (score 2):

Since everyone is just commenting, let me state two more solutions that might teach you something about how to use [`Slot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html) and [`SlotSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SlotSequence.html)

```
list = {Subscript[1, a], Subscript[2, b], Subscript[3, c]};

Tr[#1 & @@@ list]
Plus[## & @@ (#1 & @@@ list)]
```

What happens is that `#1& @@@` will replace the `Subscript` in `list` with a function that simply returns the first argument. Then you only need to add all elements up.

In the second case, we obfuscate this summation a bit turning the list of numbers `{1,2,3}` into the *sequence of numbers* `1,2,3` with the help of the function `## & @@`.

Note that you could use `Sequence` instead of `##&` but how boring and readable would that be?